# highlight last 3 number in the string

Tags: php

how to highlight last 3 number in the string:
ab9c5lek94ke72koe8nsk9

i want output:

> ab9c5lek94ke7**2**koe**8**nsk**9**

i tried following:

```
$str = "ab9c5lek94ke72koe8nsk9";
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str );
$last3 = substr($numbers, -3);
$highlights = str_split($last3);
$output = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $highlights).'/i', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

but it highlight:

> ab**9**c5lek**9**4ke7**2**koe**8**nsk**9**

Comment: shall consecutive digits be recognized as single number?

Comment: @Jin-ohKang i just need last 3 numbers in the string to be highlight, in my case 289.

Comment: if the input is `dag2vue41a89au76zhz30`, is the output `630` or `89, 76, 30`?

Comment: @Jin-ohKang no, only 6 3 0.

Comment: so it should be highlight like this: dag2vue41a89au7**6**zhz**30**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that easily using regular expression with PHP's `preg_replace()` function. Just find last 3 digits 3 times at the end of the string. See the following code:

```
$str1 = 'ab9c5lek94ke2koe8nsk9';
$str2 = 'dag2vue41a89au76zhz30';

echo preg_replace('/(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)$/mui', '<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>$4<b>$5</b>$6', $str1);
echo preg_replace('/(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)$/mui', '<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>$4<b>$5</b>$6', $str2);
```

Outputs

> ab9c5lek94ke**2**koe**8**nsk**9**

and

> dag2vue41a89au7**6**zhz**30**

Comment: when i tried: dag2vue41a89au76zhz30, output will be: dag2vue41a**89**au**76**zhz**30**. i need output like this: dag2vue41a89au7**6**zhz**30**. last 3 number 6 3 0.

Comment: Edited my answer. CHeck out please!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a regex like below:

```
/(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)$/
```

which is basically `(\d)([^\d]*)` 3 times with a `$` sign at the end. It means we are matching a digit followed by 0 or more non digit characters. Note that we do need the `$` sign at the end to match ***only last 3 digits***.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "ab9c5lek94ke2koe8nsk9";

echo preg_replace('/(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)(\d)([^\d]*)$/',"<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>$4<b>$5</b>$6",$str);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/PoYCG

The replacement string is just having the bold tags with group number of the matched strings which are to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on the 3rd from last number, then highlight everything in that sub string and then recombine the substrings.

In my example, I get all of the numbers in the string and put them in array. Then I use that array to get the delimiter (72 in your example), then use that to split the string into two arrays, at that point you can highlight everything in array[1] and then combine it back into array[0]

```
$str = "ab9c5lek94ke72koe8nsk9";
// get all of the numbers in order and place into it's own array
$numbers = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', ' ', $str ));
$numbers = preg_split('/\s+/', $numbers);

// using that get the delimiter to where to split the string. and split.
$delim = $numbers[count($numbers)-3];
$arr = explode($delim, $str);
$arr[1] = $delim . $arr[1];

// then highlight everything in $arr[1]
// then combine $arr[0] and $arr[1]
```